# Speed up the data retrieval from Documentum via DQL

Tags: java, dql, documentum, dfc

I am doing a Java project connected to Documentum and I need to retrieve data from object table. The thing is when I retrieve from 1 table I can get the answeres in max 2 seconds for each of the following tables with the following DQLs:

```
SELECT * FROM cosec_general
```

and

```
SELECT * FROM dm_dbo.cosec_general_view
```

however once I want to join those two tables together in retrieve from the result it takes 5 min to do so. 
Is there any way that I can make it faster? 
Here is the DQL that I use to join them I get teh columns that I need:

```
SELECT dm_dbo.cosec_general_view.name, dm_dbo.cosec_general_view.comp_id, 
dm_dbo.cosec_general_view.bg_name, dm_dbo.cosec_general_view.incorporation_date, 
dm_dbo.cosec_general_view.status, dm_dbo.cosec_general_view.country_name, 
cosec_general.acl_domain, cosec_general.acl_name 
FROM dm_dbo.cosec_general_view, cosec_general
```

Comment: youe second query is incomplete

Comment: @Miki Why do u think so ? :) I can use it to retrieve data successfully though

Comment: you are doing something wrong. try elaborating your question a bit more. show more code around your queries

Comment: if your query is complete than what you have wrote isn't join, or more exactly, it's full outer join. how big are tables/object types in your repository?

Comment: @Miki oh I meant that they join successfully but when I test it in DQL tester it takes me 5 min to retrieve all the data .( The only problem is the time that I want to reduce ) . It's quite big . The results should be around 190 000 lines :D

Comment: I'm asking you: is there a lot of data in those table. Because if it is, then it's logical you need a lot of time to retrieve it. What DQL tester you use? Does your Documentum server or DB server have enough resource to deal with your queries? Your question is very broad, please narrow it describing it in more details

Comment: well you said it all. since you are using term "DQL tester" I beleive you mean Repoint od DQMan. Both are old and unsupported java applications that need to load and display retrieved data. It's expected that you need that much time for it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no condition on which fields you are trying to join,
Add WHERE clause containing condition for join, like 
`WHERE dm_dbo.cosec_general_view.field_1=cosec_general.field_2`

Comment: Thanks for your answer I had already figured that  mistake out  :D

Answer (score 0):

You are using wrong approach. In query

```
SELECT * FROM cosec_general
```

the asterisk `*` means return me everything. Once you loaded information to the memory object manipulation with it should be measured in milliseconds.